# Angular 2+ timer for to app the same, what would be the best approach?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-services, timer, synchronization

I want two independen Angular application, which should have sycronised timer. The timer should start let's say 12min. and count to 0. Which means, I have a timer on Angualr-App-A which get started and the Angular-App-B should also start at the same time. If I stop the timer at Angular-App-A than the timer at Angular-App-B should also be stopped. Of course it should show the same time at anytime. I was thinking if I generate a timer service on at a WebService which give me the status (Start/Stop) and the actual time. But I am not sure if the delay of a network would destroy sync on both ends?

Or do I need to pair this to application which each other and not talk trough a webservice. So, I can start a timer on app-A and send it every 1 second on app-B but with this I also have a delay.

Does anyone have a idea to have a good approach on that? Or is the WebService a good idea?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a solution? The App-A will get from a NTP service the time at any start. The App-A will publish (somehow) to App-B the calculated endtime. App-B will fetch the actual time on the same NTP service and calculate the rest time. This might have a lack of few millisec. but I think this would be a valid approach?

Comment: I solved the problem with using WebSocket Communication